# How do I prevent assign errors when using union types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Imagine I have these interfaces:

```
   interface FirstElement {
      id: string;
      coordinates: Coordinates;
      type: FirstElementTypes;
      options: FirstElementOptions;
    }

   interface SecondElement {
      id: string;
      coordinates: Coordinates;
      type: SecondElementTypes;
      options: SecondElementOptions;
    }

    interface FirstElementDTO {
      id: string;
      type: FirstElemenTypes;
      options: FirstElementOptions;
    }

    interface SecondElementDTO {
      id: string;
      type: SecondElementTypes;
      options: SecondElementOptions;
    }
```

Now I want to create a DTO object, mapping these interfaces to their corresponding DTO interface. Because they share the same properties, with only the options being different, I'd like to use a single converter function. But when using typescripts union typing like this...

```
  private static convertElementToDTO(element: FirstElement | SecondElement): FirstElementDTO | SecondElementDTO {
    return {
      id: element.id,
      options: element.options,
      type: element.type
    };
  }
```

...I (obviously) get an error message telling me that the options are not compatible. Would it be possible in typescript to "tell" a function that if `FirstElement` is the input type, `FirstElementDTO` is the output type and vice versa for `SecondElement` - without writing the same code multiple times and using several if-statements? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your function is violating the single responsibility principle, and over time it could end up doing too much work. Instead you could use a convention based mapping framework e.g. https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper. I appreciate this is not answering your question, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: @BenSmith Is there a general consensus where the line between the single responsibility princinple and writing redundant code is? From my understanding, having several code snippets doing basically the same thing would be considered unclean-code. Am I wrong here? Thanks a lot for the link, I'll check it out!

Comment: The key would be refactoring the code so that the "several code snippets" which do the mapping use common code, which is what automapper does. Also on the topic of redundancy, with your code FirstElement and SecondElement could derive from a BaseElement which would have "id" and "type" in it.

Comment: @BenSmith In my actual scenario they do derive their properties from a BaseElement. Only the options property is different for each element. But AutoMapper looks like it could help, thank again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function might work here.  First, some dummy type definitions to make the code here a self-contained example:

```
type FirstElementTypes = { FirstElementTypes: true };
type FirstElementOptions = { FirstElementOptions: true };
type SecondElementTypes = { SecondElementTypes: true };
type SecondElementOptions = { SecondElementOptions: true };
```

Then we can represent your types this way, to reduce code duplication:

```
// your types
interface FirstElementDTO {
  id: string;
  type: FirstElementTypes;
  options: FirstElementOptions;
}

interface SecondElementDTO {
  id: string;
  type: SecondElementTypes;
  options: SecondElementOptions;
}

// define elements as extension of DTOs to reduce code duplication
interface FirstElement extends FirstElementDTO {
    coordinates: Coordinates;
}

interface SecondElement extends SecondElementDTO {
    coordinates: Coordinates;
}
```

And finally here's the generic function:

```
// generic Pick function
function convertElementToDTO<E extends FirstElement | SecondElement>(
  element: E
): Pick<E, "id" | "options" | "type"> {
  return {
    id: element.id,
    options: element.options,
    type: element.type
  };
}
```

And it works without error:

```
declare const f: FirstElementTypes;
declare const o: FirstElementOptions;
declare const c: Coordinates;
const first: FirstElementDTO = convertElementToDTO({
  id: "firstEl",
  type: f,
  coordinates: c,
  options: o
}); // okay
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAECsFcGcBdWgewLYFNSwJ4Ad0BNUAzASwDtjZjFToNFRkBDAa3VgAtjbGFUAbQgFoAxtViMyqPKFQAPRsmx9UAKCy5QAMWIAnOAFFlaUrAAqOVLQC8oAN5bdBo6hPnc0AFwYdkdAF8AbjULBz1YQ1RjWAB5bEpqaztQp0iXGLiqGi9YH38g9XQAZVRRUjwIqLdLUBt7YtLy51cLT29fUEDgjXrqRtSTWPiaGqSesoq0wczWnPbOlRBQTERIHQwWlTJYVB1CRmF0bTCJkwARU2i7FVBQYjwvOB0yAHMgm4KvI5TKlrfQRAyCU+jnCTXSQ2gQT8Kk2Jh2ewOoDGfSi50utmut3uCByLz+HyRJV6JzMv0xAIhXmRJKmCShMMWBBIpHQ-H6sG4tDk2xomX+hFAaNosHoOikkERogIoDwkCUxGEjCGsO2u32hxBJJksh5eFoX1B7LRVxuN1EiB0eDISssXgAwogLVbSDbISpoSr4erCQ0tdyXHqfcSwcaMabQObLdbtq0HU7o5Z6QswM8XDsFaAAAoK5igQiQUjCZX5wtDCPUABuO0NlUQaIAPPptbr9ZqwaAAD5B8ZggB8AApMWyol59CoAJRebPCZiNgA0oAARHdF52lxTpquu4uCoveybQGLYKtSAebncvMO0gA6O5zzE3DdAmRg69Pmj38MEq8ma8FTGdB6jKRAkOQ2hg7BKhB6BSugADuFrMNAKgEMIfCMGK5Y0PAhDAscYJVG6qHoZhpRwP8eHfJMgI0EExEYTBoERvajpRi6MZBGROEgpRNZpMaNilFWOh8a4dYXP2YZYl4i4kPhi6fusuBeIQimRs6rpeMIinvq0iDuuOQRAA)

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond ! No, the actual input element types also differ in a `type` and `genericType `. Your approach seems to be pretty close to what I'm looking for though, but I get an `Property "options" is optional in type Pick <FirstElement, "id" | "options"> but required in type FirstElementDTO` error. Any idea why that might be? I haven't quite gotten the hang of generics yet...

Comment: I think I need a definition for `FirstElementDTO` before I could say what’s going on.  And if your definition of `FirstElement` in the question is different from what is being mentioned in that error, then I’m also at a disadvantage.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your edited code, but I simply cannot reproduce the error you mentioned in your comment here.  It always helps to make the effort to provide a [mcve], preferably one can be demonstrated via a link to an online IDE like the Playground.

Comment: As always, it was a stupid mistake. In `FirstElement` I marked a property as optional and overlooked it, same for `SecondElement`. That property was not optional in the corresponding DTOs. Your suggestion of demonstrating it a playground was very helpful here, I'll keep it mind in the future. Your function works perfectly, thanks a lot for taking the time!